# Where to find message output in Oozie?

Tags: oozie

Really simple question for newbies of Oozie. Where do I find message outputs from those `<message>` tags in workflow xml? I tried /path/oozie-distro/logs/oozie.log but there are only system level messages.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. If [Hue](http://gethue.com/) is a part of your distribution open 'Workflows/Dashboard' tab.
2. There is Oozie Web UI. To install it properly follow [Oozie installation guide](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_QuickStart.html). It's not activated by default in Cloudera distributions - see [how activate it](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/archives/cloudera-manager-4/v4-5-1/Cloudera-Manager-Enterprise-Edition-Installation-Guide/cmeeig_topic_13.html). Usually it's available at the port 11000.
3. Be aware that all Oozie jobs and actions are run in a Map Reduce cluster. Check administration UI of your Map Reduce cluster (usually available at 50030 port) to see any jobs run by Oozie.